# How can the radial distortion be corrected by given supporting points in order to obtain a linear image?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, linearization

Five lasers with fixed angles (0°, 5°, 10°, 15°, 20 °) radiate through an aspherical Fresnel lens and project their non parallel beams onto a diffusing screen (focusing screen).
A camera is directed rectangular to the screen.
[The Installation is shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efnI7.png)
The camera has a resolution of 1388 (H) by 1038 (V) pixels. The image center is therefore located at pixel position x0 = 649 and y0 = 519.
The following radial pixel distances to the image center were measured:

- Laser angle : Pixel distance to the image center

  - 0° : 0
  - 5° : 171
  - 10° : 334
  - 15° : 476
  - 20° : 599

The laser angle is therefore non linear to the pixel distance (Delta: 171, 163, 142, 123).

The non-linearity results from the distortion of the Fresnel lens. This distortion should now be corrected (equalization).

My approach:
Scaling the distance of each pixel to the image center (x0 = 649 and y0 = 519), where the scaling factor is the lens function L of the respective distance r to the image center:

- x' = x0 + L(r)*(x - x0)
- y' = y0 + L(r)*(y - y0)
- r² = (x - x0)² + (y - y0)²

x' and y' are the corrected pixel coordinates.
The lens function L has the value of 1 for the image center:
L(0) = 1.

**Now my question:**
How can I determine the lens function L(r) from the given 5 supporting points (0, 171, 334, 476, 599)?

Please help and post a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "distortion", do you mean that the lens is _not_ a flat plane perpendicular to the "0°" direction? But somehow it nevertheless manages to deflect the beams such that they are exactly parallel after emerging from it?

Comment: The lens is perpendicular to the "0°" direction, i.e. the "0°" laser beam goes directly through the middle of the flat Fresnel lens. The five lasers are mounted in a fan style shape (like a chinese handheld fan) and placed in the focal point in front of the lens. Therefore the laser beams are parallel to each other after passing through the lens. The screen is in parallel to the lens.

Comment: x @Cheesy: That does not match the numbers you give. By your description the displacements at the screen cannot possibly be other than proportional to $\tan(v)$, so your deltas should increase rather than decrease.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: So I have to check if the lasers are really in the focal point in front of the lens (maybe a measurement error).

Comment: I've checked the installation again (see Image above) and it was my fault. **The laser beams are non parallel to each other after passing through the lens**.